# Android - Only I can see photo shared on Facebook from the app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am new to the Facebook SDK and I have a problem sharing a picture from my app. When the ShareDialog appears and I tap on "Post", the photo is correctly published on my profile, but I am the only one that can see it; if other Facebook users open my profile they can't find the picture.

I already checked and it's not a problem of privacy (the post is usually visibile to friends).

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide what you have done, It's seems that you are sharing a private content, try to share public content like url to the post or the image.

Comment: Have you checked the Facebook settings of your application, it might be private.

Comment: Where can I check the Facebook settings of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was so simple. I had only to log in my Facebook developer profile and set my application as "live" in the tab "App Review".